# How to use office 365 Api and stock the user name in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, office365

Background:

I already have a website en langage PHP and SQl (including Login and the main page);right now I want to connect with Office 365.
It is to say that I have two ways to login: one is from my own website,another is through the account Office 365.After login with office 365,I can get the name of the user and search the name in my database, according to their name I will give them different rights(read,write....)
I have the API code from office 365,but I don't know how to use it.Right now I just can sign in the account of office and jump in to the main Page.

Problem:

----- I don't konw how to stock the 'user.profile.name' in PHP?
When I jump in to another page, it doesn't keep the information of the Office 365.And I can not compare the name of the user with my data base.

----- And because the API code is in javascript, How to stock the parametre in PHP?

Office  365 API Code(this is the login page for office 365):

```html
  
<html>
<head>

<!--META-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login Office</title>

<!--STYLESHEETS-->
<link href="css/stylelogin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--SCRIPTS-->

<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.12/js/adal.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var ADAL = new AuthenticationContext({
      instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
      tenant: 'common', //COMMON OR YOUR TENANT ID

      clientId: 'XXXXXXX', //This is your client ID
      redirectUri: 'XXXXXX', //This is your redirect URI

      callback: userSignedIn,
      popUp: true
  });

  function signIn() {
      ADAL.login();
  }

  function userSignedIn(err, token) {
      console.log('userSignedIn called');
      if (!err) {
          console.log("token: " + token);
          showWelcomeMessage();
    window.location.replace("main.php") 
      }
      else {
          console.error("error: " + err);
      }
  }

  function showWelcomeMessage() {
      var user = ADAL.getCachedUser();
      var divWelcome = document.getElementById('WelcomeMessage');
   divWelcome.innerHTML = "Welcome " + user.profile.name;
    
  }

   

</script> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=" images/favicon.ico" /> 
</head>
<body>
<button class="button" id="SignIn" onclick="signIn()">Sign In</button>


<h1 id="WelcomeMessage"></h1>



</body></html>
```

I have tried a lot of methods to stock the 'user.profile.name',
for example session,cookie,txt,post,but I didn't successed.

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem,Thanks.